# Which method is fire every time the view appear - Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am coming from iOS background and I am very new to **Nativescript**. I want to know is there any equivalent method to iOS **viewWillAppear** in Nativescript.

I want to update listview everytime the view is appearing.
I have tried following methods. Nothing can do the job

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("onInit called");  
}
ngDoCheck(): void{
    console.log("ngDoCheck called");
}
ngAfterContentInit(): void{
    console.log("ngAfterContentInit called");
}
ngAfterContentChecked():void{
    console.log("ngAfterContentChecked called");
}
ngAfterViewInit():void{
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit called");
}
ngAfterViewChecked(): void{
    console.log("ngAfterViewChecked called");
}
ngOnDestroy():void{
    console.log("ngOnDestroy called");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NativeScript `loaded` event ([API reference](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview#loadedevent))

```
<ListView (loaded)="onListViewLoaded($event)"></ListView>
```

And then in the component file

```
onListViewLoaded(args) {
    let list = <ListView>args.object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular makes use of Change Detection in order to check the View.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

You can make use of the following

```
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges { 
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log("fired"); // fired each time change detection runs
  }
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with nativescript, i will try to answer you using Angular.

Angular came with component life cycle once you create the component. So, if you destroy your component and recreate it again, you can use ngAfterViewInit.

Or if you create the component only one time and just hide/show it, you should do it using Angular directive to hock on visibility property of your view.

Note: if you gave the component any input property and it will change on show/hide the component you can use ngOnChanges, but Angular call it only if any component input parameters changed or the component placed on the changed detection tree.